# Specific AD group does not get permission in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, ad

I want to restrict access to a site in Sharepoint Online.

I have disabled inheritance and created a new Contributor Sharepoint group, called [Site] Members.

When I add Active Directory (AD) group A to this Sharepoint group, and use "Check permissions" it shows the expected result. 
But when I add AD group B, "Check permissions" shows that its members don't have access.

Both AD groups A and B are non-nested, meaning they only contain users, not other AD groups. They are also both Security groups and similar in every way.

If I add users from group B to the Sharepoint group directly, then "Check permissions" reports that they have access.

Why doesn't group B work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the users in Group B had both normal and Administrator user account types, and group B only contained the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a check on user information list. If group B is listed there, please remove it and re-grant access to Group B.

If Group B is not in that list, try to add Group B with powershell `Add-SPOUser` and see if the issue remains.

You can submit a service request for further help from MS support team.

Update: [Information about User information list](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/User-Information-List-in-8b420e8c).

If nothing helps, you can simply ask for a service request and the MS support team will provide further help.

Comment: where do I find the "user information list"?

Comment: @Rugbrød Please check the link i update.

Comment: I see group B in the list

Comment: @Rugbrød Sorry for the late reply, have your tried to remove group B from the user information list and re-add it?

Comment: If it's safe to do, then I will try it.

Comment: @Rugbrød It does not cause impact on your site, simply it removes the record of the group from your SharePoint site. Then you can re-grant Group B permission had have a try to see if it works

Comment: I tried it but it made no change.

Comment: @Rugbrød Then it may be better for you to ask for service request.